# Unable to read csv from S3 using R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I am trying to read a csv from AWS S3 bucket. Its the same file which I was able to write to the bucket.When I read it I get an error. Below is the code for reading the csv:

```
s3BucketName <- "pathtobucket"
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "aaaa",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "vvvvv",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-east-1")

bucketlist()

games <- aws.s3::get_object(object = "s3://path/data.csv", bucket = s3BucketName)%>%
   rawToChar() %>%
  readr::read_csv()
```

Below is the error I get

```
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>_data.csv</Key><RequestId>222</RequestId><HostId>333=</HostId></Error>
```

For reference below is how I used to write the data to the bucket

```
s3write_using(data, FUN = write.csv, object = "data.csv", bucket = s3BucketName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to include the protocol (s3://) or the bucket name in the object parameter of the `get_object` function, just the object key (filename with any prefixes.)

Should be able to do something like 
`games <- aws.s3::get_object(object = "data.csv", bucket = s3BucketName)`

Comment: This worked for me in terms of being able to load, but i get some kind of hex response: s3.load.csv('test.csv')
  [1] 73 69 67 6d 61 2c 72 2c 70 72 6f 62 0d 0a 32 2c 30 2e
 [19] 32 35 2c 31 0d 0a 32 2c 30 2e 32 35 32 2c 31 0d 0a 32
 [37] 2c 30 2e 32 35 34 2c 31 0d 0a 32 2c 30 2e 32 35 36 2c
 [55] 31 0d 0a 32 2c 30 2e 32 35 38 2c 31 0d 0a 32 2c 30 2e
 [73] 32 36 2c 31 0d 0a 32 2e 31 2c 30 2e 32 35 2c 31 0d 0a
 [91] 32 2e 32 2c 30 2e 32 35 2c 31 0d 0a 32 2e 33 2c 30 2e
[109] 32 35 2c 31 0d 0a 32 2e 34 2c 30 2e 32 35 2c 31 0d 0a
[127] 32 2e 35 2c 30 2e 32 35 2c 31